# CSS 1 px border with responsive bootstrap, Vimeo embed, and WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, vimeo

I have a problem with the embedding of a video in my WordPress theme with Vimeo. 1px border of the Vimeo background on the left side of the video embed shows up (in Chrome). Bootstrap is also implemented with this theme.

Basically when the Vimeo iframe is embedded it show a very thin black border at the left that is the Vimeo default background for its iframe. We have a white background so it is very noticeable on some pages. If you view source the basic embed is:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/64685575" width="940" height="528" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

But the actual embed is much more complex and has bootstrap fluid styles put onto it and such. I have tried inspecting all the elements and editing them but can't figure it out. Good example of a page having this problem is: http://www.universityoffashion.com/disciplines/fashion-art/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is incorrect. .player .video-wrapper is in the HTML document loaded into the iframe, therefore !important does nothing since the iframe literally loads a different web page inside of the frame which is in no way affected by the local CSS. There have been multiple reports of this problem on Vimeo over the past year, and they are essentially non-responsive.

My solution was just to put my iframe inside a div with position: absolute, top: 0, left: 0, width: 100%. That width is 100% of the parent of the div, which in my case is constrained by the column widths in my responsive layout. This actually works, unlike the answer previously marked correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change background color of video wrapper div. A div with class video wrapper has the background of #000. Change it to #fff.

The following is the code in player.css at line no 2.

```
.player .video-wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Replace it with:

```
 .player .video-wrapper {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: I can't actually change the .player .video-wrapper {} because that is included with the iframe as part of Vimeo. I don't control that CSS file so it can't be changed. There is something else that is making it go off my 1px it has something to do with the responsive row-fluid :before :after I think. The black line will actually switch sides if you shrink the browser window.

Comment: you can write it in your css file which is being loaded. And just add the code and write !important for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with inline css in iframe tag and it worked and its responsive as well.

```
<iframe ..... style="border:1px solid;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to expand the width and height of the iframe 2px top and left. After that, centralize the iframe within the container wrapper.

The wrapper has overflow hidden, than, the 1px border is gone.

```
/* Embed iframe wrapper */
.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16 x 9 */
}

/* Vimeo/Youtube Iframe */
.embed-responsive iframe{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  border: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me,
`you must put this in the div which has the iframe inside:`

```
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
border: 5px solid gold;
box-sizing: initial;
```